# Azure Functions v2: Integrate Unit Tests with xUnit in Deployment with Azure DevOps

Tags: .net-core, build, azure-devops, azure-functions, xunit

I created an Azure Function v2 (.NET Core) and added a Core Class library that includes Unit Tests using xUnit. I then created a Build pipeline in Azure DevOps with the tasks Visual Studio build and Visual Studio Test.

But I repeatedly fail to build successfully respectively to have the Unit tests running successfully in the pipeline. Locally everything works fine.

What do I have to do to get the Function App build and unit tested successfully in the Azure DevOps Build pipeline?

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolve this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps that have made it work:

- Create the Core Class Library
- Reference the Azure Function project via "Add Reference"
- Add NuGet packages to the class library -> xunit, xunit.runner.visualstudio and Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
- Add classes to the class library as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#create-test-classes
- Go to to the .csproj file of the Azure Functions project as well as the class library for the unit tests and change

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

- Set up the Build pipeline and include the following tasks:

[image]
........................................................
[image]
........................................................
[image]
........................................................
[image]

- Make sure that all files are added before checking in (TFVC) /
  pushing (Git)
- Check in / Push